# How to get field values from Global Set using Element API plugin?

Tags: globals, plugin-elementapi

I'm pulling data from a Global Set using the [Element API plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) and am wondering if there's a cleaner way to write the transformer function?

My `craft/config/elementapi.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/settings' => [
            'elementType' => 'GlobalSet',
            'criteria' => ['handle' => 'siteSettings'],
            'first' => true,
            'transformer' => function(GlobalSetModel $siteSettings) {
                return [
                    'defaultTitle' => $siteSettings->getContent()['defaultTitle'],
                    'defaultDescription' => $siteSettings->getContent()['defaultDescription']
                ];
            },
        ],
    ]
];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no need to go through `getContent()` to access your field values; you can access them directly from the GlobalSetModel:

```php
'transformer' => function(GlobalSetModel $siteSettings) {
    return [
        'defaultTitle' => $siteSettings->defaultTitle,
        'defaultDescription' => $siteSettings->defaultDescription
    ];
},
```

Comment: That's what I was initially expecting, however when I try to access the field value as an attribute of $siteSettings, no values are being returned. Are there any gotchas I may be missing on the setup of the globals?

Comment: @Coppa Are `defaultTitle` and `defaultDescription` just regular Plain Text fields, or something else?

Comment: Ahh, great call. They're rich text fields (I changed the name of these fields for display on SE). I just tested a plain text field, and that let me access the value as you described. I was able to get the value of the rich text field using getParsedContent(). Thanks for the quick help!